# What influences the visibility of QLCDNumber digits?

Tags: qt, qt5, qlcdnumber

I do have the following code:

```
  Address = new QLCDNumber(this);
  Address->setDigitCount(4);
  Address->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
  Address->display(mValue);
  mainLayout->addWidget(Address);

  Value = new QLCDNumber(this);
  Value->setDigitCount(8);
  Value->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
  Value->display(mValue);
  mainLayout->addWidget(Value);
```

And the result is shown below. I see the only difference in the number of digits. If I change the number of digits for the first QLCDNumber to 6, it also gets thinner. How can I make the second, 8-digit number better visible?

[image]

Comment: If it is possible in your design, you could try to change the size of `Value`. It has the same size as `Address` but it can show more digits so Qt resize the digits accordingly. For example, try this: `Value->setMinimumSize(QSize(200,200));`

Comment: I defined the size !only! defining the number of the digits, and expected that Qt will do the rest.

Comment: Well, Qt resizes the widgets depending on your layouts if you don't set the size. [Example](https://gist.github.com/ftena/dd803188d027a7b40058).

Answer (score 2):

```
  Value = new QLCDNumber(this);
  Value->setMinimumWidth(Value->width()+1);
```

solves the problem, so I guess it is a kind of rounding error in the `QLCDNumber` size (or segment shape?) calculating algorithm.